# How to setup SAML?

Tags: sso, saml, single-sign-on

I am learning about SAML and already read many articles and forums but I still having confusion about setup IdP.
I am using "https://simplesamlphp.org/"

For example, I have 3 websites "example.com", "one.example.com", "two.example.com";
All are on three different server.
Now, I want to setup single sign on login using SAML then on which server I need to setup IdP.
As "example.com" is main domain which has all the information about user.

As I learn, when I login to "example.com" then it sends request to IdP.

But I don't get any idea where I have to set IdP and what Idp contains?. 
Its on same server where "example.com" hosted OR its different server and what logic I have to write on that server?
It's simple login function OR I need to setup "simplesaml" for this and set login logic to there.

After setting up IdP, what I need to do on other server "one.example.com", "two.example.com"?
Do I need to install again "simplesaml" to both server and set SP and IdP?

In sort, which server has IdP and SP? And on which server I need to install "simplesaml"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I understand that you are learning about SAML, but unless you have a specific need for SAML, I would recommend you to look a OAuth instead as it is much simpler. OAuth can provide the same SSO experience that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare SAML to OAuth in the following way:

- SAML IdP (Identity Provider) is an Authorization Server.
- SAML SP (Service Provider) is a Resource Server.

Your SAML IdP should be running as a stand alone service and you can set it up on a domain name of your choosing e.g. `idp.example.com` or `auth.example.com` etc.

On any page where you want to have SSO, you must configure it as a SAML SP and configure it to accept SAML assertions from your IdP. This is typically done by installing a certificate from the IdP in your SP.

When you are going to `www.example.com` and you click `Sign in using SAML`, your website should redirect you to the IdP server, where you will enter your credentials (once). Then the IdP will redirect you back to the SP with a signed assertion containing your identity.

The next time you are going to a page and click the sign in button, the IdP will still remember you (depending on configuration).

---

You seem to be concerned about domain names, and I will try to clarify:

It does not matter to SAML what your domain names are. Your SP can be at xyz.example.**net** and your IdP can be at abc.example.**com**. Everything is handled through HTTP redirects.

Just remember that you must use public domain names that you own if you want to use a trusted certificate authority. And you should definitely use HTTPS on all of your sites.

Comment: I got you comment but my main concern is where to I have install "simplesamlphp". Its only on one site OR all site?

Comment: simplesamlphp acts as an IdP and should be setup once on a separate server. On your individual sites you must setup SAML using a client library (as a server provider) and you may find a library in the respective programming language. For PHP libraries, you can go to packages.org e.g.